# Could hibernate be causing this 'fetch out of sequence' error?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am attempting to execute this query (in an Oracle DB) with Hibernate/Spring JPA:

```
@Query( value = "DELETE from MY_TABLE where ID = :ID", nativeQuery = true)
    void delete(Long ID);
```

There is a BEFORE DELETE trigger on the table that is making up for poor table design that I **cannot** change, it runs around deleting rows from dependent tables so that the base DELETE doesn't cause any foreign key errors. I am fairly sure this shouldn't be an issue, but if it is let me know.

Now then, on execution this query causes a `ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence` error which, according to google, is caused when `a fetch has been attempted from a cursor which is no longer valid`. (To be completely clear, I have not initiated any cursors with my query or my trigger)

**BUT**, the row and all its dependants *are* **actually being deleted successfully**. Because of this I am not sure what is causing the error and would like yalls' help

Comment: @Nitika answer is correct, help community by accepting it, the answer resolved my problem

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method should be :

```java
@Modifying
@Query( value = "DELETE from MY_TABLE where ID = :ID", nativeQuery = true)
    void delete(@Param("ID") Long ID);
```

Try this and check if the issue still exists.

Comment: I am now getting a ``javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: `` exception. The calling method was already wrapped in ``@Transactional`` and wrapping the delete method directly does not change the outcome. 

Interestingly the rows are not being deleted any longer?

Comment: what is the package name you have imported for @Transactional ?

Comment: javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional

Comment: your import is wrong. it should be org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import this package and then check.

Comment: This was my issue, just need to ensure that you also add the @Transactional annotation to the method as well

Comment: Are you able to point me to the documentation that is explaining what is happening behind the scenes with why adding `@Modifying` will fix the issue.

Comment: I wish also get it more understandable too!